# how to use Like Operator with in clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  SELECT column-name FROM table-name WHERE 'value' IN (column-name,column-name,column-name)
```

I want to use like operator for 'value' so If someone type val instead of value so result should come

please help me out

Comment: show some dummy data

Comment: you should first learn how SQL works, and especially the WHERE clause, and the LIKE keyword. follow tutorials, try manually on your own database). then try to write code that does what you want, and if it fails, come here again, explain in detail what exactly you want (you are currently not clear enough in this) and show us the code and how it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Change `in` into the `or`s

```
SELECT column-name 
FROM table-name 
WHERE column-name like '%value%'
      or column-name like '%value%'
```

and so on. If table is big this can be really slow query.